# Login in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, web, web-development-server

hello guys i finished to learn django and build and personal project on it. But, when i tried to add custom user model (using AbstractUser), i added email column in User model and set email as a login in my login form, it doesn't work
So take a look at piece of my code

## This is my login func in views

```
def login_page(request):
    page = 'login_page'
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email").lower()
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        print(email, password)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            print(user.password, user.username, user.email)
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, "Can't Find User")
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Wrong Username Or Password!")

     context = {'page': page}
     return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)
```

## This is my custom user model with email setted as USERNAME_FIELD

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="avatar.svg")

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

## This is my html that catches the password and email

```
      <form class="form" action="" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% if page != 'login_page' %}
                <div class="form__group form__group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="e.g user_user" />
                </div>
                <div class="form__group form__group">
                  <label for="username">Email</label>
                  <input id="username" name="email" type="text" placeholder="e.g. user_user" />
                </div>
              {% else %}
                <div class="form__group form__group">
                  <label for="username">Email</label>
                  <input id="username" name="email" type="text" placeholder="e.g user@user.com" />
                </div>
              {% endif %}
```

So for e.g i have the user with credentials: username - admin, email - admin@email.com, password - Lovell32bd
I have some debug print statements

```
- [07/Jul/2023 07:44:25\] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6526
- www.cool444@gmail.com Lovell32bd
- Lovell32bd tim www.cool444@gmail.com
- \[07/Jul/2023 07:44:38\] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6467
```

It PRINTS OUT the email and password
IT FINDS THIS USER IN DB

But this function doesn't log in the user
the problem in this line:

```
user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Wrong Username Or Password!")
```

If you try to print out the 'user' it returns **None**

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is something to do with your user model. make sure that you have informed Django to use **your User model** by adding the following line to the `settings.py` file.

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app_name.User"
```

And also I hope to have a **custom user manager**. This article may help you

- https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/
- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

And it's a good idea to use Django forms instead of writing a form from Sketch.

Comment: @deadloveelll3333 If you can provide your custom user model manager, it would be helpful to identify what's going wrong.

Comment: hello dishan, i have this line in settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'base.User'

Comment: and i misunderstand your question, what exactly do you need?

Comment: Did you write a custom manager for your custom user model

Comment: no, i didn't write it

Comment: I think that is the problem when you're using a custom user model that inherits from the `AbstractUser` model you want to write a custom user manager. In simple words what the manager does tells how to save the user into the database (in your case) it is easy to do you can follow the articles I mentioned above. I think that will solve your problem.